# WebBluetooth writeValue is too slow and writeValueWithoutResponse does not work

Tags: blazor, thermal-printer, web-bluetooth

I am trying to print an image on a thermal printer, but it's printing too slow. Printing does work, but each line takes about 1 second to print, which means an entire image takes 20-30 seconds. If I compare that to other apps that work (such as Loyverse), it prints the same image in less than 1 second.

I'm using a library for Blazor called [Blazm.Bluetooth](https://github.com/EngstromJimmy/Blazm.Bluetooth). There is a [JavaScript file](https://github.com/EngstromJimmy/Blazm.Bluetooth/blob/main/Blazm.Bluetooth/wwwroot/Blazm.Bluetooth.js) that it invokes, and inside the JS file is the following:

```js
export async function writeValue(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, value)
{
    var device = getDevice(deviceId);
    console.log("Found device" + device);
    if (device.gatt.connected) {
        var service = await device.gatt.getPrimaryService(serviceId);
        var characteristic = await service.getCharacteristic(characteristicId);
        var b = Uint8Array.from(value);
        await characteristic.writeValue(b);
    }
    else
    {
        await sleep(1000);
        await writeValue(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, value);
    }
}
```

To invoke this method, I simply call the following method:

```cs
await navigator.WriteValueAsync(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, bytes);
```

However, since I cannot send more than 512 bytes at a time, I have to split my image into 512 byte chunks. If I then foreach over the chunks, I can send the whole image at once, but it takes way too long for it to print:

```cs
foreach(var bytes in chunks)
{
    await navigator.WriteValueAsync(deviceId, serviceId, characteristicId, bytes);
}
```

I thought it might have something to do with the `await characteristic.writeValue(b)`, as it might wait for a response, but if I replace the deprecated `writeValue` with `writeValueWithoutResponse`, I get the following error:

> gatt operation failed for unknown reason

Any clues?

Comment: More in general (I don't know the device nor the library), if you can rewrite/reimplement the method so it will take an array of chunks as `value` and perform a `characteristic.writeValue()` on each chunk without having to first get the primary service and characteristic for each individual write, that may already speed things up.

Comment: @robertklep Yeah I tried to set the service and characteristic first, then reusing those values, but it didn't speed it up. I've grabbed the HCI log from my phone and opened it in Wireshark, and I can see that each byte array is 127 bytes long. So I tried to chunk it into 127 bytes, but it's still slow.

Comment: Does the characteristic support write without response? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BluetoothCharacteristicProperties/writeWithoutResponse

Comment: Along the lines of Vince's comment, can you connect the HCI log from Loyverse printing to the device and see what the difference in timing is and whether it is using write without response or some other method to send lots of data more quickly?